# How do I bypass the character limit when setting up a new rule in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm working with a database containing information on MPs. I'm trying to set up a rule that would colour code entries in the "MP name" column, according to party (eg if I enter "Rachel Maskell" into the list, the text would turn red).

I've tried using the "new rule" function but I keep running into character and cell limits. If I try and enter all of the relevant MP names straight into the "format only cells with:" box in the new rule tool I exceed the character limit. If I try and select a column containing all the relevant MP names and use that as my referent I get a error message telling me I've selected too many cells.

Is there a way I can get around this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add your input and expected output? How many cells are you selecting??? how much text to bypass the char limit?

Comment: Hi Foxfire! The sheet I'm working with is a log of MPs' tweets, with columns for date, name, tweet, and some tags. The column I'm trying to make a rule for is the name column. It currently contains 13335 entries. The input I've tried to use for the rule is 2292 characters long (list of Labour MPs, in this case). My output would be the name column, as it is now but colour coded. Does that answer your question? Often I find I don't even have the right vocabulary to discuss the problems I encounter with excel.

Comment: **2292 characters long** is too long. Can you post here your data input? Can ypu post the rule? Otherwise, this a shot in the dark

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

[image]

[image]

Sorry I don't know much about politics